# How to overwrite include wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, include

I have a plugin that imports a template via `include` in a long and complicated function called `frontend_box`, drawing the main interface.

In my own plugin I want to hook into this template and basically replace it with my own functionality. The one I am interested in is called `template-add-to-cart-variable.php`. Here is how the function looks like

```
function frontend_box($object, $helpers, $EVENT) {
    ...
    if(!$event->is_cancelled() && !$stopSelling && !empty($woometa['_price'])):
        ...
        if( $product && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ):                                                                                      
            include($evotx->addon_data['plugin_path'].'/templates/template-add-to-cart-variable.php');
        endif;
        ...
    endif;
    ...
}
```

How can I tell wordpress to include a different php file when hitting this `include` line without change the plugin code?

Comment: Simply replace the include line with your own! ```include("path/to/yourown/template");```

Comment: I don't want to change the plugin core files, so that I can be update it in the future without changes.